# Embedded YouTube iframe not visible inside article

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

I embedded an iframe into a responsive div and article on my page. When I click on where it is the audio will play but the video id blank. I tested this with another iframe placed outside of the article and that one works fine. This is only happening in Chrome, and I made sure that my browser is updated.

```
<article id="content">
    <div id="about" class="divider">
        <h1>Job Title</h1>
        <article class="videos">
            <h2>Videos</h2>
            <div class="video-box">
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/YhNzFcp7e2M?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>

    <div class="">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/YhNzFcp7e2M?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</article>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src=jquery-ui.min.js></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#hamburger').click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
            $("#nav-bar").toggleClass('open-nav');
        });

        $('#about article').click(function(){
           $(this).toggleClass("open-more", 500); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the css:

```
#about .videos
{
    width: 80%;
    height: 50px; /* the height expands to auto when clicked */
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 0;
    background: navy;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.videos .video-box
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56%;
}
.video-box iframe
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

This is just to resize the iframe, it was doing this before I added this.

As I said, the first one won't show up, but the second one works fine.

Comment: It is probably something to do with "videos" or "video-box" classes. Can you share them too?

Answer (score 0):

Your are doing `$(this).toggleClass("open-more", 500);`

The above will simply toggle the class "open-more" to the article, but unless you have some other css somewhere, it won't do anything.

You could try the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('#about article').click(function(){
    if ($('#about article').height() == 50) {
        $('#about article').css('height','auto');
    }
    else{
        $('#about article').css('height', '50px');
    }
    });

});
```

On click, the condition will check if your element height is set at 50px, if it is, it will change it to auto, else put it back at 50px

Here's a [Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tjmo7c4r/)

Comment: My script works fine it's the video that's the problem. Someone asked for the script so I posted it. The video still doesn't show up in the Fiddle so this doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: You might be having a browser problem since the 2 videos are loading fine when i open the fiddle, using Chrome Version 67.0.3396.79, also works on Firefox for Ubuntu 61.0.1 (64-bit)